# How to make Web Api secure against CSRF attacks in ASP.NET?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, csrf, csrf-protection

Consider a web application that consists of only HTML and JS for Front end and that communicates with a Web API.

I am trying to protect my application against CSRF attacks and for that I have took reference of [this article](https://dotnetthoughts.net/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks-in-webapi/).

Using the methods in this article, I am able to generate Anti CSRF tokens and pass it to the client. However it depends on first AJAX call that must happen before making regular CRUD operation calls.

With this approach, I need some clarity on few things as well as some alternatives if any. Consider a client visits this web application (which is protected by AJAX based Anti CSRF token), and keeping his session open, he visits a malicious website that contains page that makes the same AJAX calls to get CSRF tokens (assume that attacker is aware of this process), I suppose he can use the headers to make unintended calls thus resulting in an attack.

So how can I protect my application against these?

Please provide more detail regarding this, or if its misleading then help me by providing correct details so that I can tackle it better.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use an encrypted communication with the server so the attacker won't be able to read any header data.

If your attacker uses the same calls as you do, he is not be able to guess the anti XSRF token that you use in your calls. A new token is generated for every call to your API. I hope this page helps you with some details:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Okay however let's assume the attacker is a trusted user of the application and with malicious intent he tries to trick another user into accomplishing something, in that case encrypted communication might fail unless I am mistaken. Also since the html page that will contain js code to get the token will take advantage of this, it can generate token and make the further calls, I guess.

Comment: So your user is logged in. He gets a form to manipulate data over ajax calls and this form comes with a anti CRSF token, witch is not more than a unique number value. So he sends the form and your API checks if the token is valid for this user. The communication is encrypted, so the attacker can't intercept the message and manipulate data. 
Just to make if clear: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks)


And yes, the attacker could still hijack the session but he can't guess the token of your user

Comment: I am not saying that user will be able to steal csrf tokens from other valid user's response. I am trying to say that even the attacker is a valid user of the application and he is trying to trick other valid user into doing something without him knowing, and for that he requires csrf tokens and since he can get these tokens directly from ajax call 'GetToken', he just has to add these to cookie and header and his malicious action will be validated on behalf of the tricked user. So is there a way we can stop such attacks ?

Comment: I am really sorry, but I don't get your point even after the third read through. If ha can log in into your application, yes he can request tokens and send valid requests. But if you enable the attacker to be an authorized user the problem is an other one and has nothing to do with the anti CSRF tokens.

Comment: its not that I am enabling the attacker to be an authorized user. Instead a valid user decided to do CSRF attack on behalf of other valid user.

Answer (score -2):

I think if we use token based authentication, client have to pass authentication token in each request. And if client do not store it in browser cache and store it in localStorage then browser will not send token in call automatically. And if our service receive any request without auth token then it will discard the request.

Comment: This question is about Cross side request forgery (CSRF). Your answer is about normal authentication tokens.